# Search Records in RDLC Report FromDate to ToDate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search

I have a report,the data of the report is coming from a Table Tbl_Orders in which i have a column named CreatedDate.

I have a search above the report in which i need to search by Name and search by FromDate to ToDate.
For example if i select any date from FromDate and a Date from ToDate records should be displayed between selected dates.

Below is my Query

```
CREATE PROC Sp_Search_RatingAndReviewsReport (@Name nvarchar(200),
                                              @FromDate nvarchar(200),
                                              @ToDate nvarchar(200))
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT a.*,
           b.Name,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(20), a.CreatedDate, 105) AS Date
    FROM Tbl_CustomerRating a
         LEFT JOIN Tbl_Customer b ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
    WHERE (b.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
        OR @Name = '')
      AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(20), a.CreatedDate, 101) BETWEEN (@FromDate) AND (@ToDate));
```

If I'm using the above query its working fine for searching by
FromDate to ToDate but i'm unable to search by name and if i remove 
this line

```
(convert(nvarchar(20),a.CreatedDate,101)between(@FromDate)and(@ToDate))
```

then its working fine for searching by name but i'm unable to search by FromDate to ToDate

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Remove the comma a end of previous line b.Name,

Comment: @jdweng `b.name` only appears in the OP's SQL twice and only once is it preceded or proceeded by a comma (`,`), in the `SELECT`. Both of those *need* to be there as `b.name` is both preceded and proceeded by another column in the `SELECT`. `SELECT a.* b.Name` and `...b.name CONVERT(nvarchar...` would give syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is known as a Catch-all or ["Kitchen Sink"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) query. These are best handled with **parametrised** dynamic SQL.

I *assume* that all your parameters are optional (although if `@FromDate` is pass then so should `@ToDate`). Therefore most likely what you want is something like this:

```sql
--Removed prefix, per comment under question
CREATE PROC dbo.Search_RatingAndReviewsReport (@Name nvarchar(200) = NULL, --I ASSUME that Tbl_CustomerRating.Name is an nvarchar too?
                                               @FromDate date = NULL, --Why was this an nvarchar? How many dates exist with unicode characters?
                                               @ToDate date = NULL)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT CR.{List your columns}, --If you''re seeing braces, you haven''t replaced this as directed' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + --Replace this with your columns, don't use * in a precompiled object
               N'       C.[Name]' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               --Created Date is already in your previous a.*, therefore no need to repeat it. 
               --If you want it in a specific format, then get your presentation layer to do that, not SQL Server
               N'FROM dbo.Tbl_CustomerRating CR' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + --Customer and Rating start with C and R, not "a"
               N'     JOIN dbo.Tbl_Customer C ON CR.CustomerId = C.CustomerId' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + --Customer starts with C, not b. Also changed to a JOIN due to the WHERE
               N'WHERE ';
    --Now for the fun part, the dynamic WHERE
    DECLARE @WHERE nvarchar(MAX) = N'';

    IF @Name IS NOT NULL --If @Name isn't NULL, add it to the WHERE
        SET @WHERE = @WHERE + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND C.[Name] = @Name'
    IF @FromDate IS NOT NULL OR @ToDate IS NOT NULL --If either of the dates aren't NULL add it to the WHERE (note that is one is NULL then no results will be returned)
        SET @WHERE = @WHERE + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND CR.CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate'
    SET @WHERE = STUFF(NULLIF(@WHERE,''),1,8,''); --The NULLIF will turn the value to NULL if no parameters were supplied
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + N';';

    PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
    --EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Name nvarchar(200), @FromDate date, @ToDate date', @Name, @FromDate, @ToDate; --Uncomment to run the dynamic statement
END;
```

Note there are **alot** of comments in that SQL you need to digest, and also you need to change the section in braces (`{}`) (per the adjacent comment).

You can then test run this and you get the below results:

```sql
EXEC dbo.Search_RatingAndReviewsReport;
```

Returns nothing (no PRINT, not dataset), as no parameters

```sql
EXEC dbo.Search_RatingAndReviewsReport @Name = N'John Smith';
```

Would run the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT CR.{List your columns}, --If you're seeing braces, you haven't replaced this as directed
       C.[Name]
FROM Tbl_CustomerRating CR
     JOIN Tbl_Customer C ON CR.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE C.[Name] = @Name;

EXEC dbo.Search_RatingAndReviewsReport @FromDate = '20190101', @ToDate = '20190601';
```

Returns the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT CR.{List your columns}, --If you're seeing braces, you haven't replaced this as directed
       C.[Name]
FROM Tbl_CustomerRating CR
     JOIN Tbl_Customer C ON CR.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE CR.CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate;
```

And finally:

```sql
EXEC dbo.Search_RatingAndReviewsReport @Name = N'Jane Bloggs', @FromDate = '20190101', @ToDate = '20190601';
```

Would run the SQL:

```sql
SELECT CR.{List your columns}, --If you're seeing braces, you haven't replaced this as directed
       C.[Name]
FROM Tbl_CustomerRating CR
     JOIN Tbl_Customer C ON CR.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
WHERE C.[Name] = @Name
  AND CR.CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate;
```

*`dbo.` does not appear in the printed SQL above, as I added it to the SP's definition after I had pasted the executed values above.*

Comment: The problem is the comma.  See my response above.

Comment: @jdweng no it isn't.

Comment: The OP said following : " i'm unable to search by name and if i remove this line
(convert(nvarchar(20),a.CreatedDate,101)between(@FromDate)and(@ToDate))"  There is no reason removing the line should have not produced any results.  That is why I prefer with a SQL Query to put the commas at the beginning of the line to prevent these type errors.  You can't have a comma before a "FROM".

Comment: Read the OP's full sentance @jdweng *"if i remove this line {SQL Statement} then its working fine for searching by name but i'm unable to search by FromDate to ToDate"* That is one sentance. the commas have literally nothing to do with the problem. They are clearly stating that when they provide a name (and I assume no dates) they are getting no results. Probably because they are (foolishly) supplying the "date" `''` (aka 01 January 1900) and they have no customers that were created on that date.

Comment: *"Not working"* means nothing to me @murtuza . What's the error you're getting or the unexpected, opr the undesired behaviour? What does "your best friend" tell you about the SQL being run?

Comment: i'ts showing empty report when i'm searching @Larnu

Comment: What is your `EXEC` statement @murtuza?